# How to write commands on second level of command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, prompt

If my batch file looks like this

```
cmd

exit
```

Then I call this batch file from command prompt
I want `cmd` to open another level of prompt and exit from there

But whats happening is that after it goes on second level and waits for a command and if I type `"exit"` there It returns to first level and execute the second command from the batch file which is `"exit"` and closes the command prompt.

Comment: Put them in another file and execute that....

Comment: You mean you want the new `cmd` window to open and then close by itself, as if having executed the `exit` command?

Comment: yeah
a new cmd window should open execute some commands and close by itself

Comment: Wouldn't you achieve the same effect (visually) if you just put the commands into a batch file and invoked the file with Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
CMD /k cmd
REM 
EXIT
```